# How to parse this xml element

Tags: javascript, java

I have an element which is empty, but there is space which has come, what are the best ways to put in a check for this in java ?

```
<element /> instead of <element/>
```

I have already tried for check like `if(element!=null)` and `if(element is not empty)`
but it did not work for me

Comment: Is that Javascript or Java? Are you using any XML parser, and if so, which one?

Comment: The best way to parse XML is to not write code to do it yourself. Use an existing library. Anything else means re-inventing the wheel; and be assured: your wheel will be very much deficient to what already exists.

Comment: Thanks will do that

Answer (score 0):

use the power of strings

```
st.replaceAll("\\s+","")
```

this eliminates all whitespaces and non visible characters